# Finding a vegan sausage in Frankfurt

Tags: germany, food-and-drink

I was in Hamburg for a few days and I easily found a vegan burger.  It amused me to eat this in the home of the hamburger.

Now, I am in Frankfurt and I am trying to repeat the game but I am having less success.

Where can I find a vegan or vegetarian sausage in Frankfurt?

Note that I am no longer looking for a burger.  I can find those.  I am looking for something which vaguely resembles a frankfurter.

It could be a restaurant, a fast food chain, or a street stall.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The global veg food listing site Happy Cow has [a few listings in Frankfurt](https://www.happycow.net/europe/germany/frankfurt/), including a shop called [Best Worscht in Town](https://www.happycow.net/reviews/best-worscht-in-town-frankfurt-152294), which offers both animal-based and Vegan currywurst. You can also investigate the [Biometzgerei Spahn](https://www.biospahn.de/), an organic butcher which again offers both animal-based and plant-based products, though it is not quite clear to me if they offer prepared foods or only things to cook at home.

Comment: I had not even started to look for this when my wife spotted another branch and suggested it.  It was just what I wanted.